# Can we use name "Aleem"?

Tags: naming, asma-ul-husna, names, aqidah

My name is Farhan Alim. Al- Aleem as we know that the name of Allah. 
Now my question is that can i use the word Alim in my name? 
Is it permissible in Islam? 
What scholars say about it?

Answer (score 1):

Khâlid ibn al-Walîd's name means "eternal", he didn't change it. Ultimately it depends on your intention (nyia). I don't suppose you consider yourself "all knowing".

One [opinion](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/35391) says "anything besides Allah and Rahmane is allowed".

Another [opinion](https://islamqa.info/en/114309) is more explicit but still says the same thing: Anything that can apply to other than God is okay; but something (like Ghafûr) that only applies to him is forbidden. And they site "Hakeem" as *not* only applying to him, so, I guess Alim can be considered that way too.